# Passing variable outside of anonymous function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have file this piece of code:

```
var result = '';
     files.forEach(function (file) {

        fs.readFile(generateTemplatePath(fileType), 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            var fileString = fs.readFileSync(baseDir + fileType + '/' + file).toString();

            var content = escapeCharacters(fileString);

            result += data.replace('{{data}}', content);
            console.log(result);
        });
        console.log(result);
    });
```

Problem is, first `console.log` prints consecutive values, but second one prints empty string. How to pass result outside of `forEach`for example as function's  `return`value?

Comment: `readFile` is asynchronous so any code *after* `fs.readFile` will run *before* the callback you passed to it.

Comment: The simplest solution is to embrace callbacks and do all your operations inside the callback instead of returning. You will probably want to use promises though if you want all of the callbacks to be executed in order.

Comment: example: ```var result = '';
     files.forEach(function (file) {
  
  var promise = return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   fs.readFile(generateTemplatePath(fileType), 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
     return console.log(err);
    }
    var fileString = fs.readFileSync(baseDir + fileType + '/' + file).toString();

    var content = escapeCharacters(fileString);

    result += data.replace('{{data}}', content);

    resolve(result);
    console.log(result);
   });
  });
  
  promise.then(function(result) {
   console.log(result)
  })
    });```

Comment: @PhillipChan but if replace second console.log(result) with return result i get undefined